# jsonp request with AngularJS $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined the following 2 services in AngularJS. Both should return JSONP since I'm doing a cross domain request.

Service A:

```
angular.module('ServiceA', ['ngResource']).
  factory('A', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('url/offers', {},
       {
         get: { method: 'JSONP', params: {property_code: 'DEMO_ERFOLGX', adults: '2',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
       }
    );
  });
```

Service B:

```
angular.module('ServiceB', ['ngResource']).
  factory('B', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('url/search.json', {},
       {
         get: { method: 'JSONP', params: {property_code: 'DEMO_ERFOLGX', adults: '2',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
       }
    );
  });
```

In my Controller, I'm binding the result to my scope:

```
$scope.foo = A.get();  
$scope.bar = B.get();
```

According to my console.log() output, B returns the expected result in JSON format, while A returns something like:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
{"DEMO_ERFOLGX":{"offers":[{"checkin":"2012-12-01","checkout"
```

Am I missing something? What do I have to do, in order to receive proper JSON from A?

Comment: Service B returns the expected result in JSON format, while Service B returns something like:  --> do you mean server A ?

Comment: sry, I had a typo here. Service A returns the error. Service B works fine

Answer (score 12):

Your code looks confusing. Both services were called A but you use different module names. Apart from that, does it matter that your second service calls a JSON file whereas the first one doesn't?

I would try the following:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('ServiceA', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('url/offers', {},
       {
         get: { method: 'JSONP', params: {property_code: 'DEMO_ERFOLGX', adults: '2',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
       }
    );
  });
  .factory('ServiceB', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('url/search.json', {},
       {
         get: { method: 'JSONP', params: {property_code: 'DEMO_ERFOLGX', adults: '2',
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} }
       }
    );
  });
```

Comment: @mawo So the problem is solved or does it still exist? I would then check if the error depends on the JSON resource you are querying or if its AngularJS.

Comment: problem solved. it turned out that the server did not return valid jsonp. thanks anyway!

Comment: how does one inject it when its coded this way, i.e. im trying to call it in my controller, but i cant just `controller(abc', ['$scope','app.services', funcion`

Comment: ok, i thnjk i know where im going wrong there, i was trying to put `services`in the list in controller() instead of the list in module(), however im cointinually getting errors on the file app.js which contains my controller, where i try to use this module.  can you give an example of how you call and use it in the controlle rplease, for your module suggestion? @F Lekschas