# How to access the RESTful services from external server in my server in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, resources, angular-resource

I am running on domain server1.

I have my RESTful services on server2.

I want to access this RESTful service on my webpage using angularjs. I tried this way. But it's returning an empty array. No data was bind. Why? any suggestions. Here is my sample code.

Comment: Your sample code didn't make it into your post.

Comment: can you please see the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/anil123/jHDF7/

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, your resource definition looks like this:

```
var UtilService = $resource('server2/users/:userId', { },
    {
        'get' : { method: 'GET',headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, params: { userId:'anil' } , isArray : true }
    }
)
```

That URL appears to be relative. If you're trying to target a remote server, you're going to need a resolvable URI. Unless that's something that was mangled in the anonymizing of your example, I think that's your issue.

Comment: Thank you for that. Thats not a relative URL, I am providing the actual url there. There I am running my server1 on localhost:8000 and server2 on localhost:3000.

Comment: Pardon the question, but...you have submitted this request manually to server2 and verified that it returns good results when the Angular front end is taken out of the loop?

Comment: If I try the same URL manually, I am getting the service results. But unable to get in this method?

Answer (score 0):

You're having a similar problem to me I think. It looks like a SOP (same origin policy) issue. You can't access a different port on the local host without using JSONP or CORS. (I've got a question open with how to do this using CORS at the moment but there are plenty of docs available on the net for JSONP). [see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234546/jsonp-request-with-angular-resource)

Hope this helps.